# Put Flutter's MaterialApp within Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display Flutter's MaterialApp in a centered container with a maximum width and height if it is viewed as a web app. Intuitively, I thought it should work with something like the following, but that doesn't have any effect:

```
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 500, maxWidth: 500),
  child: MaterialApp( ... )
);
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to do? It's a bad idea to have multiple `MaterialApp`. You could use webView type of packages or create your UI in such a way that it reflects a web app.

Comment: I just want to have my (single) MaterialApp in a centered box if it is viewed as a WebApp, so that it doesn't spread out too much on bigger screens. I know I can do this with the body content, but I would like things like the AppBar or FloatingActionButton to be within the constrained box as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Launcher());

class Launcher extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GenericScreen(), // or any screen using routes param
      builder: (context, child) => child!,
    );
  }
}

class GenericScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FractionallySizedBox(
      widthFactor: .8,
      child: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but only for relative values. How can I define a maximum width and height in absolute values?

Answer (score 0):

**There is a pub called Flutter Web Frame:**

Make the frame max width / size when on large devices such as Web or Desktop.

This is very suitable to be used to limit the size of content,
if your application is not yet available a responsive version if it is run on multiple devices / platforms.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_frame